# What earth are the various DC animated shows set in?

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe

The Marvel Cinematic Universe is Earth-199999, making it an actual universe within the Marvel multiverse. However, what earth do the various DC animated shows take place on. The shows I am referring to are:

- *Young Justice*
- *Teen Titans*
- *Teen Titans Go*
- The various shows of the DCAU
- *Green Lantern: The Animated Series*
- *Beware the Batman*

And let's throw in *Super Friends* because who's going to stop us? If there are any series I missed, do elaborate on them as well.

**EDIT:** I would also appreciate the various animated movies, too, such as *The Killing Joke* and *Justice League Dark*.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_animated_universe

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Most of these show take place on their own, unnamed and unnumbered Earths. Of the ones you named, this includes *Beware the Batman*, *Green Lantern: The Animated Series*, and *Superfriends*. *Teen Titans Go!* is a spin-off of *Teen Titans*, so they share the same universe, but it is otherwise separate. Of these, only *Young Justice* has (to my knowledge) a place in the New-52: it's set on Earth-16.

The major exception here is the DC Animated Universe (DCAU), which was a shared continuity that included bunch of animated series and movies (plus some other stuff, of questionably canonicity). This universe is actually it's own isolated multiverse (there's 3-4 Earths on it), and was active from 1992 through 2006. The list of series set in this universe are:

- *Batman: The Animated Series* (1992-1995)
- *New Batman Adventures* (1997-1999)
- *Batman Beyond* (1999-2001)
- *Superman: The Animated Series* (1996-2000)
- *Static Shock* (2000-2004)
- *Zeta Project* (2001-2002)
- *Justice League* (2001-2004)
- *Justice League Unlimited* (2004-2006)

As far as animated movies are concerned, they also generally exist in their own isolated universes. Again, the DCAU is an exception, as it included the Batman animated movie series:

- *Batman: Mask of the Phantasm*
- *Batman: Mystery of the Batwoman*
- *Batman & Mr. Freeze: SubZero*
- *Batman Beyond: Return of the Joker*

(Of note: *Superman: Brainiac Attacks* *looks* like a DCAU movie, and came out at around the same time, but it doesn't share continuity).

There is also another large shared animated movie universe, called (not surprisingly) the DC Animated Film Universe, that is still active. It includes a number of existing and upcoming animated movies:

- *Justice League: Flashpoint Paradox* (*)
- *Justice League: War*
- *Son of Batman*
- *Justice League: Throne of Atlantis*
- *Batman vs. Robin*
- *Batman: Bad Blood*
- *Justice League vs. Teen Titans*
- *Justice League Dark* (upcoming)
- *Teen Titans: The Judas Contract* (upcoming)

(*) "Officially", *Flashpoint Paradox* is not part of the DC AFU -- the concept was invented by WB as a response to the popularity of that movie. However, the post-credits scenee is actually the opening of *Justice League: War*, strongly implying that *Flashpoint Paradox* is "unofficially" in the same continuity; since the entire movie takes place in an alternate timeline, there's really no room for discontinuity to occur anyway.

Comment: I don't suppose you can give the universes of some of the animated movies as well. For example, The Killing Joke and Justice League Dark.

Comment: It's called [DC Animated Movie Universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DC_Animated_Movie_Universe) not DC Animated Film Universe nad maybe time to remove that Upcoming part too

Answer (score 2):

*Teen Titans Go* has several different multiverses of the same or similar looking versions of the titans. Some are in the same multiverse but mostly each episode is a different multiverse counterpart which explains how sometimes they die and sometimes they don't. For example, there is the multiverse "Serious" that the teen titans go in ["Let's Get Serious"](http://teen-titans-go.wikia.com/wiki/Let%27s_Get_Serious).

For the link see above, these are not the same titans as these teen titans even though they look the same. For example, at the [Galactic Prison](http://teen-titans-go.wikia.com/wiki/Galactic_Prison) where Starfire is an aggravated criminal.

Comment: This is a nice answer, do you know how many universes there are supposed to be for _Teen Titans Go_?

Comment: Thank you but I'm not entirely certain of how many multi verse there are exactly sorry I wish I had more information

Comment: That's fine, we welcome partial answers too! Be sure to [register your account!](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/44557/345161)

Answer (score 0):

Young Justice is Earth-16.

The original DCAU shows and movies, including Teen Titans, is in Earth-12.

The NEW DCAMU series is a rebirth of Earth-12.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Do you have a reference for *Titans* being in Earth-12?

Comment: Originally, it was intended to be in the same Universe as the DCAU.  However, the creators later decided to consider it separate.  But, there has been no official designation of a universe for the Teen Titans.

However, I offer the following evidence that they ARE in the same universe:

Comment: Static Shock Season 3 Episode 1: Hard as Nails
Young Static Shock asks Batman, “Where’s Robin (Dick Grayson)?” 
Batman responds, “With the Titans.”
“Who?”
“You’ll meet ‘em some day.”

Static Shock Season 3 Episode 10: Romeo in the Mix
"I can’t get Robin? What about the kid in the tights? Yeah, yeah, the green one!” (Beast Boy)

Teen Titans series takes place after with the team already formed and Robin is now Jason Todd

Teen Titans Season 2 Episode 22: Winner Take All
Young Speedy appears.

Comment: Justice League Unlimited Season 2 Episode 5: Flash and Substance
Kid Flash’s costume has been spotted in the Flash Museum

Justice League Unlimited Season 2 Episode 7: Patriot Act
Speedy appears as an adult.

Therefore, chronologically, the Teen Titans should take place between Justice League and Justice League: Unlimited.

Comment: You really should add all these points to your answer!