# How to watch every DC property in perfect order?

Tags: dc, suggested-order, dc-extended-universe, dc-animated-universe

I have never seen any DC films, tv shows, read any comics or anything. I honestly know nothing. I was wondering if there is an order for ALL the films, tv shows, spin-offs and animated media like there is for Marvel like the one [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xrUoo.jpg)?

Comment: DC animations, TV series, and films all exist in different continuities - they aren't in the same universe, basically.

Comment: That graphic only covers a tiny portion of Marvel's TV and film output, basically the last ten years. It ignores the hundreds of hours of film and TV that went before and the thousands of comics and novels that preceded that.

Comment: I get why someone would downvote the question, but why would one downvote the answers?

Comment: some people like to punish users who answer bad questions.

Comment: @KutuluMike  -  it's not that bad now that I've edited it. Also, the most recent reboots aren't that old yet. If OP limits the question to most recent releases, I think the question would be ok.

Comment: @Gallifreian - Because answering bad questions encourages more bad questions. As far as I'm concerned, if you're answering something that's garnered four downvotes in ten minutes, you're not making the site better, you're making it worse

Answer (score 2):

The graphic you linked to covers a tiny, tiny fraction of the Marvel universe; it *only* tells you what order to watch the Marvel Cinematic Universe movies. It doesn't cover any of the comic books, any of the dozens of animated shows, [any of the X-Men, Fantastic Four, or Spider-Man movies (before 2016)](http://thesffblog.com/2016/05/a-guide-to-the-marvel-cinematic-multiverse/), or any live-action show before about 2010.

The equivalent graphic for DC would be very, very short. It would consist of exactly three movies:

- *Man of Steel*
- *Batman vs. Superman: Dawn of Justice*
- *Suicide Squad*

If we included upcoming movies that haven't been released yet, you could include:

- *Wonder Woman* (the movie)
- *Justice League: Part 1*

There really *is* no order to watch "all DC properties" because they all cover vastly different times. There are a good half-dozen distinct comic book timelines that overlap, cross over, or reboot each other; there's an entire [set of TV shows](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/arrowverse/info) on the CW that exist all by themselves; the *Gotham* show is separate from that; and there's [more than one animated universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/145758/what-earth-are-the-various-dc-animated-shows-set-in). And there's [a ton of movies that exist](http://thesffblog.com/2015/11/a-guide-to-the-dc-cinematic-multiverse/) outside the DC Extended Universe.